# include jar in ant compilation android  - command line linux

Tags: android, linux, ant, command-line, jar

I'm trying to use a jar file in an android application on the linux command line. I've read:
[Android include .jar in ant compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108026/android-include-jar-in-ant-compilation)
Which is the same thing but never got a working answer.
Tried this:
[How to add external jar libraries to an android project from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217643/how-to-add-external-jar-libraries-to-an-android-project-from-the-command-line)
but it didn't work, still gave the same error message.
The error is:

```
-compile:
     [javac] Compiling 4 source files to /home/bianca/Documents/sem12012/FIT3140 /code/jackson-example/bin/classes
    [javac] messagemain.java:4: package org.codehaus.jackson.map does not exist
    [javac] import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] messagemain.java:21: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ObjectMapper
    [javac] location: class messagemain
    [javac]             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] messagemain.java:21: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ObjectMapper
    [javac] location: class messagemain
    [javac]             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac] 3 errors

BUILD FAILED
/home/bianca/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:602: The following error  occurred while executing this line:
 /home/bianca/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:622: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

So I'm guessing it's a problem with importing the jar. I have the jar stored in ./lib.

EDIT:
I put the jar in libs according to a suggestion in an answer, it gives the same error.
ant.properties is all comments, local.properties and project.properties have not been changed from the automatically generated one. build.xml has not been changed, it's just the automatically generated one.

Comment: Can I see the ant file itself? Is it the automatically generated one?

Comment: It's the automatically generated one, I made changes that were suggested in my research, but none of them worked so I deleted them. I'll add it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `libs/`, not `lib/`. The JAR will automatically be included as part of the compile process, and the JAR's contents will be packaged into your APK.

Comment: @Harpy: Then your JAR does not contain the class you are trying to use.

Comment: It should, I'm trying to build an example my lecturer posted, and the library is in the jar. I'll double check that I downloaded the right version of the library, thanks.

Comment: Hm, I opened the jar and the class is in there, I've arranged to see my lecturer today, so I'll sort it out then. Thanks, I'll post what I turn up then.

Comment: Ok, turned out we were actually using different versions of the library, it works now. Thanks :).

Comment: @Harpy: Whew. You had me worried there! Glad to hear that it is working!

Comment: I am using flexjson2.1.jar and i have libs folder itself but i am not getting it

Comment: and yes i m trying to obfuscate

Answer (score 0):

When building using Eclipse "run", you can have imported JARs even in subfolders of the libs folder - you can, for example, have it in libs/somefodler/somJar.jar.  The Ant script shipped with the SDK, however, expects it directly in the libs folder, and not a subfolder.